# Prefix route laravel and show in blade

Tags: laravel-5.1

I want to config prefix for url.File `route.php` is something like this

```
 Route::group(['prefix' => 'speech', 'as' => 'speech'], function()
{
    Route::resource('user', 'UserController', ['as' => 'speech.user']);
});
```

And in file `blade`, linkRoute is something like this

```
{{ Html::linkRoute('speech.user.index') }}
```

That's code will show error : `Route [speech.user.index] not defined.`
What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
{{ url('/speech/user/index') }}
```

Comment: it's running.One more thing, what 's url for edit user?

Comment: If work correctly accept answer .see this https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-url

Comment: This's way `{{ url('/speech/user/edit',[3]) }}`
but url correctly accept is: `../speech/user/3/edit`

Comment: Another way, `{{ Html::linkRoute('speech.user.index') }}` in my question, I did this or something like this for along time. Now, I forget the code

Comment: try this {{ Html::linkRoute('speech/user/index') }}